# What could cause these dents in a granite countertop and how can be fixed?

Tags: countertops, granite

Not sure what could have caused this. The granite is called "Blue Pearl" and it's polished.

This happened on an area around the sink in the bathroom, multiple spots. It's like certain components of the rock were dissolved by something.

Can it be blamed on a poor quality stone that was filled with something that washed away in time?
Update: pic of the sample mentioned in the comments

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually granite is thick enough to grind down smooth, no need for fillers.  Think real granite would need to hit with something hard(hammer) to cause dents, but certain cleaners/chemicals(usually not household use) might eat away at it.  Is it real granite or a covering called granite(formical/laminate)?

Comment: I've have that sort of damage in a soapstone bathroom countertop.  The damage is in places where the water has been allowed to sit.  Like OP said, it's like the soapstone has been dissolved or otherwise attacked by the water, which in our case is slightly hard.  But I wouldn't think granite would be susceptible to that.  Our granite kitchen counters, on the same water, show no such damage.

Comment: @SteveSh  Would think soapstone would be an odd choice for counters.  Think it is one of the softer stones/rocks, so it is easy to damage.

Comment: I have a sample in my hands and I can clearly see that the surface is not perfectly polished and shinny, there are matt spots that correspond to a different material natural insert, these are like the spots where it was dissolved so I guess the material is not evenly though

Comment: This doesn't look like granite.

Comment: It looks like flakes of quartz in whatever substrate for the majority of the counter surface and that some of the flakes have come out. Are you the one who originally had these counters installed? If so, give your stone people a call. Also, it appears that you have several pics on your phone there, if you would upload another pic or two, it may help people ID what's going on. ProTip™: You can simply upload the pic and don't have to upload a screen shot of the picture...

Comment: @crip659 - Yes, you're right.  It was one of those things where we were in the stone store, saw the counter with sink laying against the wall, found out it was the right size for the new bathroom vanity that was going in, went with the color scheme, and so bought it on the spot.  Would not do it again (soapstone counter top).

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. "I have a sample in my hands" - does this mean that this is a sample of counter you're considering buying? Then just ask the sales people about it. If it's already installed, please explain that statement.

Comment: @crip659 soapstone used to be used as laboratory countertops in  biology, chemistry, and physics labs installed from the 19th cent to the 1950s. Soapstone is resistant to concentrated acid, base and orgainic solvents, but is soft enough to suffer abrasion. We have soapstone counters in our house in the kitchen and one bathroom. For us granite is too "busy".   I'm sure labs use a sysnthetic replacement.

Comment: We went to the store to buy similar  for the kitchen(initially we thought we had the same in the kitchen and bathroom but it is not the same). We identified what we thought we had in the kitchen and we got a sample from the store. That is why I said I have a sample.  I put them side by side in the kitchen and it is not the same but it matches the one I have in the bathroom which has the above problem. See the update for a pic of the sample

Comment: To be sure: The first pic is your actual, installed counter, while the second is the sample, just for our information, correct? Have you asked the counter top supply company about this?

Comment: the lady that gave me the sample seemed to be a little bit off with her answers ...she could not explain it and she told me that HomeDepot might have some products to fill these gaps like this https://www.amazon.ca/MagicEzy-Stone-Fix-Durability-Guarantee/dp/B07K1VJB2S/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=stone%2Brepair&qid=1661952596&sr=8-5&th=1 but I want to understand what caused this and how it was possible since she is saying that is granite